# how can i make awk process the BEGIN block for each file it parses?

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin

i have an `awk` script that i'm running against a pair of files.  i'm calling it like this:

`awk -f script.awk file1 file2`

script.awk looks something like this:

```
BEGIN {FS=":"}
{ if( NR == 1 )
    { 
      var=$2
      FS=" "
    }
   else print var,"|",$0
}
```

the first line of each file is colon-delimited.  for every other line, i want it to return to the default whitespace file seperator.

this works fine for the first file, but fails because `FS` is not reset to `:` after each file, because the BEGIN block is only processed once.

**tldr: is there a way to make awk process the BEGIN block once for each file i pass it?**

i'm running this on cygwin bash, in case that matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using `gawk` version 4 or later there's the `BEGINFILE` block. From the manual:

> BEGINFILE and ENDFILE are additional special patterns whose bodies are  executed  before  reading  the  first
>   record  of each command line input file and after reading the last record of each file.   Inside the BEGINFILE
>   rule, the value of ERRNO will be the empty string if the file could be opened successfully.  Otherwise, there
>   is some problem with the file and the code should use nextfile to skip it. If that is not done, gawk produces
>   its usual fatal error for files that cannot be opened.

For example:

```
touch a b c
awk 'BEGINFILE { print "Processing: " FILENAME }' a b c
```

Output:

```
Processing: a
Processing: b
Processing: c
```

#### Edit - a more portable way

As noted by *DennisWilliamson* you can achieve a similar effect with `FNR == 1` at the beginning of your script. In addition to this you could change `FS` from the command-line directly, e.g.:

```
awk -f script.awk FS=':' file1 FS=' ' file2
```

Here the `FS` variable will retain whatever value it had previously.

Comment: well it turns out that my "awk" is really GNU Awk 4.0.1, so this works great for me.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
BEGIN {FS=":"}
```

use:

```
FNR == 1 {FS=":"}
```

Comment: In spirit, this is the right thing to do, but this will split everything except the first line on `:`, the opposite of what is wanted.  You need to set `FS` to a space when FNR==1 and to a `:` on the last line of the file (to split the first line of the next file on colon.)

Comment: Thank you @Dennis. Do you also have trick for END  for each file :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If you're using gawk, you can use an `ENDFILE` block. Otherwise , use a flag and save `$0` and perform your end of file action at the beginning of the _next_ file (using the FNR test and flag test) _and_ at `END`.

Answer (score 3):

The `FNR` variable should do the trick for you. It's the same as `NR` except it is scoped within the file, so it resets to 1 for every input file.

http://unstableme.blogspot.ca/2009/01/difference-between-awk-nr-and-fnr.html
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/46931-awk-different-between-nr-fnr.html

Answer (score 1):

When you want a POSIX complient version, the best is to do:

```
(FNR == 1) { FS=":"; $0=$0 }
```

This states that, if the File record number (`FNR`) equals one, we reset the field separator `FS`. However, you also need to reparse `$0` and reset the values of all other fields and the `NF` built-in variable.

This is equivalent to the GNU awk 4.x `BEGINFILE` if and only if the record separator (`RS`) stays unchanged.